# Is there a way to watch a specific property of an object in vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

[Here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watching-reactive-objects) the doc only shows a way to watch the entire reactive object using

```
const state = reactive({ 
  id: 1, 
  name: "",
});

watch(
  () => state,
  (state, prevState) => { // ...
  }
);
```

what if I only want to watch the change of the `name`?

```
watch(state.name, (name, prevName) => {
    // for example: send a request to serve side for occupation validation
});
```

The code above is wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can watch the change of a single attribute like so:

```js
const state = reactive({
  id: 1,
  name: ""
});

watch(
  () => state.name,
  (newName, prevName) => {
    /* ... */
  }
);
```

Comment: Is the same thing possible with a `computed` value ?

Answer (score 2):

```
watch: {
    'state.name': function () {
         // updated...
    }
}
```

Hopefully it would be worked on your side.

Comment: OP is using the Composition API, not the Options API.

Answer (score 0):

Watching a getter to a property of an object. Here is an example for object declaration with `reactive()` and `ref()`.

[vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive, watch } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')

const state1 = reactive({ id: 1, name: "your-name-reactive" })
const state2 = ref({ id: 2, name: "your-name-ref" })

const testingField1 = ref('')
const testingField2 = ref('')
const testingField3 = ref('')

watch(
  () => state1.name,
  (newName, prevName) => {
    testingField1.value = newName
  }
)

watch(
  () => state2.value.name,
  (newName, prevName) => {
    testingField2.value = newName
  }
)

watch(
  [() => state1.name, () => state2.value.name],   // ⬅️
  () => {
    testingField3.value = `was triggered by any one at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`
  }
)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <div>
    <input v-model="state1.name" />
    <button @click="state1.name = new Date().toLocaleString()">click me</button>
    <span>{{ testingField1 }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input v-model="state2.name" />
    <button @click="state2.name = new Date().toLocaleString()">click me</button>
    <span>{{ testingField2 }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>{{ testingField3 }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Please notice `.value` when declaring an object with `ref()`.